# multi-module maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2

If I have 6 modules in my project is it possible to build only one out of six ? without commenting out others ?

**EDIT**

Submodule will not work itselft because or parent tags. I need to install the parent first to make it build. how can I do it without installing parent

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> is it possible to build only one out of six ? without commenting out others ?

My understanding is that you want to launch maven from the aggregating project (i.e. a reactor build) but only build one module. This is possible using the **`-pl`, `--projects`** *project list* option (see [advanced reactor options](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/10/maven-tips-and-tricks-advanced-reactor-options/)):

```
mvn --projects my-submodule install
```

This is a very powerful option, especially when combined with `--aslo-make` (to also build the projects on which the listed modules depend) or the `--also-make-dependents` (to also build the projects that depends on the listed modules). On the basis of your update, you might want this actually:

```
mvn --projects my-submodule --also-make install
```

Launching Maven from the directory of the module you want to build is of course an option but this won't allow you to do the things mentioned above nor to build a subset of all modules. For such use cases, the advanced reactor options are the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Opening a command shell, navigating to the submodule directory and executing `mvn install` (or whatever your preferred lifecycle is) should do the trick.

Comment: @Péter Török I Updated my question .. your solutions is simplest so far .. I can't build submodule .. I need to install the parent first because submodule will not work itselft because or parent tags.

Comment: @Gandalf StormCrow That's a more complicated story then... I stand aside to humbly watch @Pascal perform his magic :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply build the module by going in this module directory and run the `mvn clean install`.

However, note that with this method, the dependencies with the others modules will be taken from your local repository (or the entreprise repository).

Let's take a simple example:

```
project
  + commons
  + business
```

Now, imagine that you build, on the *root* directory the whole project, using the `mvn clean install` command. Consider that all your modules are in version `1.0`.

Now, you move to version `1.1`. If you run the `mvn clean install` on the `business` project only, it will try to get the `1.1` of module `commons`. You will then have an error, as Maven will not find any version `1.1` in your local repository.

Answer (score 0):

Within Eclipse, assuming you have m2eclipse installed: Right-click on the module in question and choose Run As -> Maven package.